# React 17, problem loading sourcemap with Chrome; Errors not refer to the line of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After upgrading to `react: "17.0.2"` / `react-dom: "17.0.2"` with `react-scripts: "5.0.0"`, I noticed I can't click on error at console to bring me to code again! and this is the normal behavior before.

Now all errors refer to `bunde.js` **NOT** `index.js:NUMBER_OF_LINE` as before.

the strange thing is the same settings working on FireFox but not working on Chrome... as we see in pictures bellow

- **Results in Chrome** Version 96.0.4664.110:

[image]

- **Results in FireFox** Version 95.1:

[image]

- **Chrome Settings**:

[image]

**When I downgrade to `react-scripts: "3.4.4"`, the problem fixed but the link open empty page; not opening the line of code.**